# How to show zend framework data grid data sorted by "date" as default?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zfdatagrid

How to show zend framework data grid data sorted by "date" as default?
When i get on the page, i wish to see data grid sorted by time as default, without getting params in URL like .../order/created_DESC/

```
$testimonials = new Application_Model_DbTable_Testimonials();
        $source = new Bvb_Grid_Source_Zend_Table($testimonials);
```

Thanks.

I solved this by passing to datagrid $select instead of $object

```
$testimonials = new Application_Model_DbTable_Testimonials();
        $source = new Bvb_Grid_Source_Zend_Table($testimonials);
```

is now

```
$testimonials = new Application_Model_DbTable_Testimonials();
        $testimonials->setSortOrder('created');
        $source = new Bvb_Grid_Source_Zend_Select($testimonials->getTestimonials());
```

Comment: It's actually not the best solution, please review mine, it may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to see what your class is doing since you didn't posted that one.

But when it's usess the `fetchAll`() function you can do two things:

**Option 1**

When there is an fetchAll()-call in the Grid class you can make this one:

```
$testimonialsTable->fetchAll(null, 'date'));
```

**Option 2**

You can re-write the `fetchAll`-Method in the `Application_Model_DbTable_Testimonials` class, when you make

```
public function fetchRow($where = null, $order = null, $offset = null)
{
    if ($order===null) : $order='date'; endif;

    return parent::fetchAll(where, $order, $offset)
}
```

Please notice in the last example fetchess always will be default sorted by the date-field.

Comment: i have just passed select to grid with already set order by date.